# Codeship Pro/GitHub Trigger build on "Ready For Review" or "PR Title Change"

Tags: github, codeship

I'm using Codeship Pro, GitHub and DangerJS to drive CI and dev process in pull requests.

Is there a way to trigger codeship to run steps when a PR moves from Draft to Ready for REview?  Also would be useful to run something when the PR title changes since we use danger to enforce title is correctly formatted.

Currently we have to manually trigger a rebuild on these steps.

Comment: did you get solution for that? I'm having the same issue on my repos.